# Convert from WE8MSWIN1252 to UTF-8 in MariaDB Engine Connect

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, odbc, mariadb

I'm connecting to an Oracle DB with WE8MSWIN1252 encoding from a webserver that displays content in UTF-8 using MariaDB Connect Engine.

The code used for connecting the tables is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable ENGINE=CONNECT TABLE_TYPE=ODBC TABNAME='oracle_table_name' CONNECTION='DSN=orcl;UID=someuser;PWD=passwd';
```

I know I have to pass somewhere the expected charset, but not sure about the syntax using this engine.

I'm able to correctly display the characters connecting directly from php using this code:

```
oci_connect('someuser', 'passwd', 'host', 'AL32UTF8');
```

The `odbc.ini` file looks like this:

```
[orcl]
Driver = Oracle 12c ODBC driver
Servername = host
```

I have tried putting `Charset = UTF-8` in this file but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tries and a lot of investigation I understood that it was a matter of the environment setup.

I finally solved it writing the next line in `/etc/init.d/mysql`:

```
NLS_LANG=SPANISH_COLOMBIA.WE8MSWIN1252 ; export NLS_LANG
```

And to connect from `isql` the next line was needed in `/root/.bash_profile`:

```
NLS_LANG=SPANISH_COLOMBIA.AL32UTF8 ; export NLS_LANG
```

I was on CentOS 6, so I suppose in other environments this could not work.

Comment: In MariaDB, are you doing `SET NAMES utf8` (or equivalent)?  Are the columns declared `CHARACTER SET utf8`?  What does not "work"?